# Zend Session timeout redirect to a specific URl

Tags: zend-framework, zend-session

My application has 3 classes of users, each of whom login from different login channels. Don't ask me why this is implemented like this, but that's unfortunately not my decision.

Anyways, it would be ideal if the Zend Session timeout would redirect each class of user to it's login page rather than a default page which happens to be /login/index. I am looking at the Zend_Session_Namespace class, but it clearly doesn't have an explicit method that specifies which page to redirect the user to once a session time out has transpired.

Has anyone implemented something funky like this before ?